# Google Play downloads last forever

Tags: google-play-store

I have been trying to download several apps from google play. I've got a 3G tested connection but whatever I try to download the download lasts forever. Can I somehow reinstall google play? What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer, but a hint: you might wish to see our [google-play-store tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info), which a.o. lists common errors and their solutions. You can also check for [other answered questions tagged `google-play-store`](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[google-play-store]+download+answers%3A1) to see if someone else had that issue and was able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the apps list in settings, slide to see all apps (including system ones), open Download, clear data and cache of it, reboot and try again. If it doesn't work, try doing the same with Play Store app (you'll need to login again to your Google account).

Comment: Thanks. I followed your advice: deleted play and app cache  and was then able to download the kindle app I was trying to download to my device. Thanks.